# How to change the format of time with the timeStamp event property

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am following an example from the book "Javascript & Jquery" by Jon Ducket.
I will include the full code below but basically when I use the timeStamp  event property I get something that looks like this: 848.2650000005378 (I see it when I console.log it), this value is used to set a variable's value using the setTime() method then converted to a readable string using toDateString() method, so I get a weird date of Dec 31, 1969. I used some online Unix time converters and they all give me a value like this: 1554928763 when I enter todays daye/time. 
So why is my timeStamp event property returning a different number/format? on w3 school's site it says the timeStamp event property gets the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970, but the number looks different than any other converter I find online. ( https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_timestamp.asp )

The code is provided by the book so I did not make any mistakes typing it, is the book wrong? I am using Chrome as a browser by the way.
Sorry I am still a beginner so I am not sure if I explained my problem properly, I can try to clarify if needed.

```
$(function() {

  $('li').on('click', function(e) {
    $('li span').remove();
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(e.timeStamp);
    var clicked = date.toDateString();
    $(this).append('<span class="date">' + clicked + ' ' + e.type + '</span>');
  });

});
```

Comment: what is `e`, what is it's property `timestamp` ... and `I get a weird date of Dec 31, 1969` ... well,848 milliseconds into the epoch date is basically the epoch date, and you must be WEST of GMT, so yeah, it'll be the last date of 1969 fo ryou

Comment: ahh, I see the issue ... w3schools is, as usual, complete garbage ... event.timeStamp is **NOT** the number of milliseconds since EPOCH ... for meaningful, up to date and **accurate** documentation, always refer to MDN ... in this case read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event /timeStamp ... *This value is the number of milliseconds elapsed from the beginning of the current document's lifetime till the event was created*

Comment: Tl;DR w3schools is 90% garbage, use a respected source of docmentation - like MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/

Comment: @JaromandaX facts

Comment: Ok I did not know W3Schools was not a reliable source, but even the book I am using is wrong then I assume maybe it's outdate info then? I will check out the website you provided, thanks.